# how to limit bullets fired

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

Here's the code, please help with detailed instruction. I need to know how to set limits on shooting bullets. If you could show me how to do it with my code that would be great. I'm including the player class, bullet class, main loop and shooting mech.

```
# This class represents the Player        
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 

        self.image = pygame.Surface([20,20])
        self.image.fill(red)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


# This class represents the bullet        
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 

        self.image = pygame.Surface([10, 4])
        self.image.fill(black)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


class Shoot(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 

        self.image = pygame.Surface([10, 4])
        self.image.fill(black)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the height and width of the screen
screen_width=700
screen_height=400
screen=pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width,screen_height])

# This is a list of every sprite. All blocks and the player block as well.
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()


# List of each bullet
bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

shoot_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# Create a red player block
player = Player()
all_sprites_list.add(player)

#Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done=False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

score = 0
player.rect.y=370


bullet_count=0




# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while done==False:
    # ALL EVENT PROCESSING SHOULD GO BELOW THIS COMMENT
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done=True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == K_LEFT:  
                bullet = Bullet()
                bullet.rect.x = player.rect.x
                bullet.rect.y = player.rect.y
                all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
                bullet_list.add(bullet)



            if event.key == K_RIGHT:  
                shoot = Shoot()
                shoot.rect.x = player.rect.x
                shoot.rect.y = player.rect.y
                all_sprites_list.add(shoot)
                shoot_list.add(shoot)                        


    # ALL EVENT PROCESSING SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT

    # ALL GAME LOGIC SHOULD GO BELOW THIS COMMENT

    # Calculate mechanics for each bullet

    bulletCounter = 0

    for bullet in bullet_list:
        bullet.rect.x -= 5


    for shoot in shoot_list:
        shoot.rect.x -= -5

        # Remove the bullet if it flies up off the screen
        if bullet.rect.y < -10:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)

    # Get the current mouse position. This returns the position
    # as a list of two numbers.
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    # Set the player x position to the mouse x position
    player.rect.x=pos[0]

    # ALL GAME LOGIC SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT

    # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO BELOW THIS COMMENT

    # Clear the screen
    screen.fill(white)

    # Draw all the spites
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT

    # Limit to 20 frames per second
    clock.tick(20)

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: i want a deatailed explanation this time

Comment: *WARNING: Variable `bulletCounter` is defined but is never used* ...... *WARNING: Variable `bullet_count` is defined but is never used* ..... *WARNING: Variable `score` is defined but is never used*

Comment: Count how many have been fired then use that information to prevent any further from being shot when that number exceeds the limit.

Comment: Why is this marked as a duplicate? The other question has been removed, therefore there is no actual source people can refer to.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a gun class which have the bullet count as a property and shooting will be a function of the class.

```
class Gun(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.bullet_count = 5

   def __shoot(self, bullet_sprite, bullet_list):
      if self.bullet_count > 0:
         self.bullet_count -= 1
         bullet_sprite.rect.x = player.rect.x
         bullet_sprite.rect.y = player.rect.y
         all_sprites_list.add(bullet_sprite)
         bullet_list.add(bullet_sprite)           

   def shoot_left(self, bullet_list):
       self.__shoot(Bullet(), bullet_list)

   def shoot_right(self, bullet_list):
       self.__shoot(Shoot(), bullet_list)

-------------------------------------------------------
```

Then, before your enter your while-loop you would create an instance of the gun class and use it as follows:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and gun.bullet_count > 0:
    print "KEY DOWN"

    if event.key == K_LEFT:  
       gun.shoot_left(bullet_list)

    if event.key == K_RIGHT:  
       gun.shoot_right(shoot_list)
```